# current date minus day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query... I want to have the current date minus the weekday to get the date for all mondays. however since current_date is a date and DOW is double I'm getting an error

```
select extract(day from(current_date)) - extract(dow from current_date)
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get an error in 9.2. Anyway it will fail for the first days of the month:

```
select extract(day from '2013-02-01'::date) - extract(dow from '2013-02-01'::date);
 ?column? 
----------
       -4
```

The correct way:

```
select date_trunc('week', '2013-02-01'::date);
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2013-01-28 00:00:00-02
(1 row)
```

Comment: you're right... this is what I need.. I really appreciate it.. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select extract(day from(current_date)) - extract(dow from current_date)
```

This gets the date of the first day of the week.